Is it possible to whitelist smart contracts and ERC20 tokens to interact with via gnosis safe wallet using Safe Modules?
In order to increase the confidence of our clients we would like to limit the amount of protocols, smart contracts, and ERC20 tokens our Gnosis Safe wallet is allowed to interact with (for example whitelisting the ones we operate with).
Please let me know if such an option already exists on the market or if we need to create such kind of module ourselves.
Thank you in advance!

Thanks for asking, there is no module specifically for whitelisting contract addresses a Safe can interact with; you could easily do it by building your own module. You can find info about it in our docs.
You can also take a look at Safe support for ERC-7579 so that the module you build is also compatible with other smart accounts, and thus reusable by others.
It would actually be great to have it open-sourced so that the wider community can benefit from it! Please feel free to edit your question (or comment below) to include a link to your repo if this is something you might consider doing.
Did it answer your question?
Best, Louis

Thank you for the info provided, everything is clear. I would like to know if it is possible to apply for a grant from SafeDAO to create such a module and make it open-sourced. Thank you!

Sure, you can find info on grants here: https://www.notion.so/safe-global/Safe-Funding-Programs-7a14a7403f1f44f0bfb236a7521dac91 and when you are ready create a submission here https://forum.safe.global/c/proposals/21
